# EntityFramework 5 Include on specific level only

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, .net-4.5

When using `Include` on a POCO entity, it looks like all of the single paths are included, no matter where I set up the inclusion path.

For example, say I have three tables:

```
USER
-----
Id
Name

AUTHOR
-----
Id
Name
LastEditUserId

BOOK
-----
Id
Name
AuthorId
LastEditUserId
```

Let's suppose I want to get all of the `Book`s with the related `Author`s and their `User`s. Meaning, I'm not interested in `Book.User`.
So the inclusion would be:

```
var books = db.Book;
books.Include(b => b.Author.User);
```

But the returned object will have both the `Author` with its related `User` and the `User` related to the `Book` itself, which I didn't ask for.

Is there a way to include only the selected path and not, generically, a whole class (as it seems to be doing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say, you have a given `Book` with key `1`. This book has a relationship to `Author` = `2` and *both* `Book.User` and `Book.Author.User` refer to `User` = `3`. If you then run the query...

```
var book1 = db.Books.Include(b => b.Author.User).Single(b => b.Id == 1);
```

...EF will load exactly what you requested for, namely book 1, author 2 and user 3, and all three entities will be attached to the context. EF will also have loaded the foreign key from book directly to user (which is `3`) because foreign keys are always loaded. When the entities get loaded to the context it will detect that the `User` entity with key `3` is attached and assign it automatically to the navigation property `Book.User` because its foreign key is `3` as well. This procedure is called *relationship fixup*. It doesn't have any overhead regarding the SQL query that is run which is actually only based on your explicit `Include` request. You can't disable this behaviour.

If `Book.User` refers to another user than `Book.Author.User` the navigation property `Book.User` will stay `null` (unless the entity that `Book.User` is refering to is already attached to the context by some former query or manual attaching).

Comment: Only that's pretty bad for JSON serialization. I don't care about duplicates, I only want the objects I'm asking for. Is there any way to accomplish that?

Comment: @frapontillo: I wouldn't serialize the entity graph directly but instead create specialized classes that only contain the properties I want to serialize and then use a projection (`Select`) to fill those classes from the database.